# Is it possible to pass an id instead of the entity when creating an association between two entities?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I have an `Item` entity and a `Category` entity. An `Item` has one `Category`. My mapping code looks like this:

```
// Item.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "Category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
 */
protected $category;
```

To create the association, I use this method:

```
// Item.php
public function setCategory(Category $category) {
  $this->category = $category;
}
```

This works fine as long as I first fetch the `Category` entity from the DB. But I'm wondering if it's possible to pass an id instead of the `Category` entity. I'd like to manually set the JoinColumn `category_id` with a scalar value. But sine `category_id` isn't an actual member of `Item`, I'm not sure how I can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getReference`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html#reference-proxies):

```
$item->setCategory($em->getReference('Category', $id));
```

Comment: Please note that this approach should be used only if you are sure there is a Category with that identifier in your database, otherwise, when eventually lazy loading the object from db, an exception will be raised.

Comment: @Ocramius you can never be sure it's in the database ;)

Comment: In that case you should be ready to catch a `Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException` exception :)

Comment: @Ocramius ineteresting. I thought it wonuld't do a select and would give SQL foreign key error in a worse case.

Comment: Well, that of course during the flush operations, but if any lazy loading is happening, then you'll get a `Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException` thrown as of [Doctrine\ORM\ProxyFactory](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php#L365)